# ubuntu 20.04 LTS mkfs.xfs problem creating xfs in nvme disk on GCE GCP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, kernel-modules

Attempting to create xfs partition in NVMe disk type in  ubuntu 20.04 in GCP is throwing me this error:

```
ubuntu 20.04 , nvme disk
root@my-euwe3a-vm:/home/myuser# mkfs.xfs /dev/myvg1/my_lv
meta-data=/dev/myvg1/my_lv   isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=327680 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1310720, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
mkfs.xfs: pwrite failed: Input/output error
```

Creating it as ext4 in same logical volume(lv) is working as expected ...

Please, advice?

```
machine type: n2d-standard-4
OS image: ubuntu-pro-fips-2004-focal-v20220829
additional disk: NVMe
```

lvdisplay

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/myvg1/my_lv
LV Name                my_lv
VG Name                myvg1
LV UUID                YnXOLf-TORp-qB87-cwfy-KeEd-qHqy-dUngE5
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time my-vm, 2022-10-06 12:42:20 +0000
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                2.00 GiB
Current LE             512
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:4
```

pvs

```
File descriptor 3 (/dev/urandom) leaked on pvs invocation. Parent PID 51678: bash
PV           VG      Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   
/dev/nvme0n2 myvg1  lvm2 a--  <32.00g 1020.00m
```

Comment: you're sure that volume is not already mounted somewhere else?

Comment: volume is not mounted for sure ...

Comment: What lvdisplay outputs

Comment: updated my question with the lvdisplay output details from affected lv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue does not appear in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so it looks like an incompatibility between `mkfs.xfs` and SSD NVMe in Ubuntu 20.04.